# How do i pick the s-th value from a string inside awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following code:

```
!/bin/sh
cat $@ > C.txt
awk -v nrc="$*" 'NF>max {max=NF;s=NR} END {print (,max)}' C.txt
```

This is the sh

```
sh test.sh A.txt B.txt D.txt E.txt F.txt
```

My question is: how can i choose the s-th value of nrc inside awk after i gave it to `awk` as a value?

If i fill the empty space of `(,max)` with nrc it shows up all the files.I have tried uing grep, sed, cat, but none of these work inside the awk.

I just want to print the s-th value from nrc after i have printed the longest row.

Inside the A.txt B.txt etc. files are only random words separated by a space.

Comment: what is nrc in the question.?

Comment: `split(nrc,a); print a[s]`.

Comment: the string made out of A.txt B.txt D.txt E.txt F.txt

Comment: Please consider asking a question like this in the Unix&Linux forum of stack exchange. That's where the shell scripting guys are.

Comment: @Philippos shell scripting is also on topic here, on [so] as well as on [ubuntu.se], [su], [unix.se] and probably others. While I agree that there is a higher concentration of shell experts on [unix.se], this question is perfectly on topic here as well.

Comment: @Philippos absolute nonsense. The real shell experts are in the usenet NG comp.unix.shell but the rest of us can muddle by here just as well as at that other forum you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I'll let you add it to your script as the question wasn't quite that clear, but here's an example with `split` :

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{nrc="A.txt B.txt D.txt E.txt F.txt"; s=4; split(nrc,a); print a[s]}'
E.txt
```

Comment: what is the  delimiter that split takes into consideration by default? is it space, and if not can i give him one?

Comment: oh, it works with split, i just wrote instead of nrf, nrc

Comment: By default the delimiter, _fieldsep_,  is `FS` and it is `split`'s third argument: `split(nrc, a, " ")`, for example.